# Excel vba: object variable or with block variable not set: opening a workbook in for cycle

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function that takes a `Collection` of `resultDates` as an argument and iterates through each date there, opening a corresponding workbook and taking some data from there. However, I get a

> object variable or with block variable not set

error. That error seems to occur on the line when I set a new workbook to `budgetWorkbook` variable. I commented out everything that goes after it, since it doesn't seem to cause that problem.

```
Function getBudgetItems(stateCopy As State, resultDates As Collection)

        Dim ExcelApp As Object
        Set ExcelApp = getExcelApp()

        Dim budgetWorkbook As Workbook


        Dim tempWb As Workbook

        Dim budgetItem As Variant
        Dim currentDate As Variant

        For Each currentDate In resultDates
            Debug.Print "****TESTING****"

            Set tempWb = ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Open( _
                    stateCopy.budgetWorkbooks(currentDate))
            Debug.Print "stateCopy...: " & 
                    stateCopy.budgetWorkbooks(currentDate)
            Debug.Print tempWb.Name
            Debug.Print "path: " & tempWb.path

            Debug.Print "****OPENED****"
            tempWb.Close
            Debug.Print "****CLOSED****"

            Debug.Print "****TESTING_END****"

            Debug.Print "starting, curentDate: " & currentDate
            Set budgetWorkbook = _
                ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Open( _
            stateCopy.budgetWorkbooks(currentDate))  'this line looks to be the culprit

            'everything down here is commented out
        Next
End Function
```

I'm not sure what's the reason behind it. I tried to do similar thing - opening a new workbook and setting it to a single variable in a cycle in an isolated function and that works fine.

Here is the last of my `Debug` window:

```
****TESTING****
stateCopy...: Y:\project_name\2014\01.01.2014\workbook_name.xls
workbook_name.xls
path: Y:\prject_name\2014\01.01.2014
****OPENED****
****CLOSED****
****TESTING_END****
starting, curentDate: 01.01.2014
****TESTING****
stateCopy...: Y:\project_name\2015\01.01.2015\workbook_name.xls
```

So it looks like everything breaks right after the first cycle, while setting the second workbook to `budgetWorkbook`. If I comment out the line

```
Set budgetWorkbook = _
                ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Open( _
            stateCopy.budgetWorkbooks(currentDate))
```

the testing part goes through all cycles flawlessly, however if I return that line, the second testing opening doesn't get finished.

**EDIT:**

```
Function getExcelApp() As Object
        Dim ExcelApp As Object
        Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        ExcelApp.Visible = False
        ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = False
        ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        ExcelApp.EnableEvents = False

        Set getExcelApp = ExcelApp
End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried it without the `ExcelApp.Application`? What you have written doesn't work for me but when I remove `ExcelApp.Application` part of it both `Workbooks.Open` work fine for me

Comment: Why are the first two paths in your debug output not the same?  Shouldn't they match?  You have `Y:\VBA\test_budget_grab` and `Y:\project_name`

Comment: @Tim Williams That's the case. I made an edit to the question. Besically the line with `Set budgetWorkbook` seems to cause the issue: when I remove it the testing output is correct for all cycles, but when it's there, the testing output breaks on the second cycle. Fixed that, I was replacing that path with just `project_name` for stackoverflow.

Comment: Are you working in Excel - not clear on why you use `Dim ExcelApp As Object`...   It's possible that you're trying to re-open the same workbook before it's completely closed, so try putting a break on the `Debug.Print "starting...` line and wait a couple of seconds before continuing: does it then work?

Comment: @Tim Williams, I double checked, apart from the names, it's all the same.

Comment: Why are you opening the same workbook twice in each loop?

Comment: I think the issue is in the `getExcelApp` function which will keep creating new instances of Excel Application. If you open Task Manager then what do you see there? Several Excel.Exe listed in the processes?

Comment: @Tim Williams I added the testing part after failing to understand the root of the problem, to see how it'll go. I added the `budgetWorkbook.Close` at the end of the `currentDate` cycle, and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: @Tim Williams I wonder why, though - in the testing I open the `currentDate` workbook, close it, then open it again with `budgetWorkbook`. Then I don't close it and at the next cycle reassign the `budgetWorkbook` variable to a *different* workbook, meaning the previous workbook, while not being closed, just stays in the memory, but shouldn't interfer with the process, having lost all its pointers within the program.

Comment: @Shrivallabha Redij, I use `ExcelApp` to achieve complete invisibility of workbooks being opened. It shouldn't cause problems - I create that app only once, at the start of the function. Yes, there's a problem with Task Manager, it happens if I forget to close workbooks and quit that `ExcelApp`, but it didn't cause problems before (unless I need to edit those workbooks, otherwise they can just be opened for reading again).

Comment: @Tim Williams, Anyways, I just wanted to say I'm really thankful. I spent hours trying to figure it out. If you post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I don't think I really had an answer here...